# Cannot perform correct action after condition is met using Enumeration Flags

Tags: c#, winforms, enums, generic-list

**Method:**

- List of employees
- Each employee has a skill set, can contain several skills
- Skill set is derived from enumeration
- I want to be able to have a loop that reads the enumeration and if they contain the appropriate skill it comes out of the loop

**Code**

```
 bool success = false;
 foreach (Employee emp in employees)
 {
 while (emp.Busy != true || success == true)
 {
 if (emp.Busy == false && emp.Skills.ToString() == _skillRequired.ToString() && success == false)
 {
 emp.EmployeeWorkload = _jobName;
 emp.ShiftsLeft = _shiftsLeft;
 emp.Busy = true;
 success = true;
 }
 else if (emp.Busy == true)
 { 
 MessageBox.Show("Sorry there is no one available for this job");
 }
```

**Problem**

```
[Flags]
public enum MemberSkills { None = 0, CSharp = 1 << 0, SQL = 1 << 1, PHP = 1 << 2, Javascript = 1 << 3, Web = 1 << 4, Python = 1 << 5, Oracle = 1 << 6, CPlus = 1 << 7, Perl = 1 << 8 };

Employee e1 = new Employee(MemberJob.Employee, "Name", MemberSkills.CPlus | MemberSkills.CSharp, false);
Employee e2 = new Employee(MemberJob.Employee, "Another Name", MemberSkills.CSharp, false);
```

Because the object contains one or more `MemberSkills`, the if statement reads the object as "CSharp | CPlus" and cannot correctly perform the method. Instead selecting an employee with CSharp in their skill set. See `e2`

Comment: why are you using the left-shift operator when defining your enum? Never seen that before.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler A wise commenter in the past phrased an enumeration like that on this site I copied it because it looked more effective although it can only have 32 enumerations inside it looks less error-prone. Can you think of a better way of stating enumerations?

Comment: @DannyWatson huh, ok. Well I usually use enums without taking advantage of their 'background' byte logic. Meaning in your case, the `skillRequired` parameter would be a `List<MemberSkills>` and then just use the `Contains` method.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler thanks for getting back to me, last question; technically speaking, would that make it easier/simpler than my method?

Comment: @DannyWatson in your case the amount of code is more or less the same. For someone unfamiliar with operators and byte logic it'd be easier to read but that's about it. The only real advantage for 'my' version is that I can use a large amount of enum values, while you are limited to 32(?). Honestly, I've never come across a situation where I had had more than 6 enum values in one `List`. So I guess that's not a real advantage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a method called [`HasFlag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the `Enum` class that will do what you need:

```
var _skillRequired = MemberSkills.CSharp;

if (emp.Skills.HasFlag(_skillRequired))
{
    ...
}
```

If for some reason you can't change `skillRequired`, you'll need to parse the value to an enum:

```
var _skillRequiredAsEnum = (MemberSkills)Enum.Parse(typeof(MemberSkills), _skillRequired));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it tells me it `cannot convert string to System.Enum`

Comment: I reformatted my code along with constructors and all that jazz, the code is working as it should, you have my thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since enum is Flags, you can use .HasFlag method of enum to check whether flags are set.

Or in old way; you can use (emp.Skills & _skillRequired) == _skillRequired to see if all required flags are set.